# I'm trying to serialize a Dictionary<boolean,v> but only want to keep the values

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

I'm trying to serialize a dictionary with key a boolean and value my own class. Now I don't need the boolean in my json file like so:

```
"Componenten": {
          "True": {
            "A": "Test",
            "B": "Test"
          },
          "False": {
            "A": "test",
            "B": "test"
          }
}
```

But i want it to be like this:

```
"Componenten": {
              {
                "A": "Test",
                "B": "Test"
              },
              {
                "A": "test",
                "B": "test"
              }
}
```

Without the true and false

Comment: Then serialize the values only, not the entire dictionary.

Comment: How to do so? I'm using json.net. The dictionary is part of an object, i don't want to lose the other properties

Comment: Is your expected format even valid JSON? It is not an array nor an object with named properties...

Comment: My dictionary is called "componenten" and has two objects, a true and a false which correspond to a object with named properties A and B

Comment: As @MártonMolnár wrote, that's not valid [JSON](http://json.org/).  You would need to do something like  `"Componenten": [ {}. {} ]` making `Componenten` an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want to, instead of serializing the dictionary, serialize it's `Values` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx). For that, you may create an additional property in your object, e.g.

```
public YourClass[] ComponentsData
{
    get{return Componenten.Values.ToArray();}
}
```

And then exclude Componenten from serialization. And then, to make things even more confusing, you can even decorate your new property with attribute specifying it's name as `Componenten` (can't remember the attribute name right now). Result will look roughly like this:

```
"Componenten": [
{
    "A": "Test",
    "B": "Test"
},
{
    "A": "test",
    "B": "test"
}]
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out